# How can I make GRUB bypass Windows bootloader?

Tags: boot, bootloader, grub2

I have two hard drives, one with fedora and another with Windows XP and 7 on two partitions.

When I boot my machine, GRUB sees Windows 7 bootloader and allows me to boot windows by going through chained bootloaders.

How can I add Windows 7 and XP as different menu items and get rid of Windows 7 bootloader (at least while booting?

I looked at grub.cfg, and I found the following entry for windows bootloader:

```
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-A8F8C04CF8C01B08' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  A8F8C04CF8C01B08
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root A8F8C04CF8C01B08
    fi
    chainloader +1
}
```

I would edit this myself, but some of the code in there makes no sense to me.

Comment: If you got rid of the Windows 7 bootload you would be able to boot to it.

Comment: @Ramhound Ok, then can I at least avoid chainloading it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by restoring Windows XP's bootloader (overwriting Windows 7 loader) and then scanning with OS-prober again. This time, both showed up.